# Optimal way to synchronize saving information to file

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my code, I've got following function:

```
void OnEvent(....){ SaveData();}
```

where SaveData looks something like:

```
void SaveData()
{
    new Thread(
        ()=>
        {
            lock(data)
            {
                Serialize(data);
            }
        }).Start();
}
```

my problem is, that during the process of serialization, the event may be fired several times, and I want for serialization to be executed only once after the initial serialization process is over.

What is the best way to do this it c#?

Comment: "I want Serialization to be executed only once after the initial serialization process is over." 

Do you mean only one additional time after the first serialization (aka only twice) or exactly 1 time (after all the calls have completed) ?

Comment: Have you looked into condition variables? I'm no expert in multithreading, but this may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of issues that you need to address:

First, do not use the `Thread` class. Really. Unless you're writing a framework for parallel processing, you're almost certainly doing something wrong if you're using `Thread`. Use something like `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or (if you're in a version of .NET before 4.0) `System.Threading.ThreadPool` to schedule async execution of code.

Second, you should be aware that sharing instance variables like `data` between threads is sticky. You're much better off passing the data that you want to save *to* the async function so that there are no issues of contention or race conditions.

Third, what do you want to happen if this is the order of execution:

```
<things happen>
OnEvent fires
<things happen>
Serialize starts
OnEventFires
Serialize completes
```

Since `OnEvent` fires in the middle of `Serialize`, should it completely ignore it or should it schedule another serialization? If you answered "b" here, what should happen here?

```
<things happen>
OnEvent fires
<things happen>
Serialize starts
OnEvent fires
<things happen>
OnEvent fires
Serialize completes
```

Should *two* calls to `Serialize` be scheduled, or just one?

Comment: a single one should be enough. the event is user changing the data. obviously, if it is fired several times during serialization, I want for the data to be saved only once

Comment: @ArsenZahray: So even though serialization started *before* the second event (ostensibly meaning that it's saving the data as it was before the change occurred), you don't want to save it after that change happens?